# Why is my model properties reset to null on post-back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I create a view model and let the user edit one of the properties. On postbac/submit, the user-edited property is correct, but other properties reset to default (null) value.

In the lower method I want to access Shift property, but it is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Anders, Denmark

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Status(int shiftId)
    {
        var shift = await _shiftRepository.GetByIdAsync(shiftId);
        var transition = await _shiftChangeRepository.GetByIdAsync(shiftId);

        if (!_permissionService.CurrentUserMayViewShift(shift,transition))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NotAllowed");
        }

        // No prior transaction => ask user what to do
        if (transition == null)
        {
            var transitionStartModel = new TransitionStartModel(){Shift = shift};

            return View(transitionStartModel);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

-

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Status(TransitionStartModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model.EnumTransitionTypes == EnumTransitionTypes.ReportSick)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("StartFlowReportSick");
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's the problem. You say shift property is null, are you saying that `await _shiftRepository.GetByIdAsync(shiftId);` returns null? If so, if ShiftId set correctly?

Comment: pleas add your view code...are your inputs in <form> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller will only receive values that the page sends to it. If you don't put them in the page, they won't be there.

You can place them in hidden fields if you like, or retrieve the original object from your data store to just update the one property you want the user to modify (this would prevent anyone from tampering with values they're not supposed to change, so that is what I would advise you to do for most values).

Answer (score 1):

In your View, for the fields that you may want to display but you do not want to edit, and you want the values back in the Request, use "HiddenFor"

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyFieldThatWontBeEdited)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyDisplayOnlyField)
```